# how to write code to click on dropdron button

Tags: maven, selenium, xpath

I have a list of applications. How to write a code to click on dropdown so that I can take a screen shot when I click on dropdown button which displays the list of applications.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are drop-down work on click event then this can help u :- 
You can locate specific drop-down and click and then u can call screenshot method